# Convert byte[] to audio(mp3) using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, binary, byte, blob

I'm storing several mp3 files in MS SQL Server'08 as BLOB objects (I use filestream). There's a WCF service which can send one of this objects to html client.

Preliminarily I convert BLOB to byte[] using ToArray(). 
How to convert incoming byte[] array to audio(mp3) and play it?This's only javascript/html on client.

I use SoundManager2 http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

to play audio.

Thanks!